# Android SQL Or Request. Which Is It?

Tags: android

Do we have to use request for mobile apps in web sites that run with a database?
Like *Facebook, Instagram, Twitter* these kind of sites mobile apps works with database or request system?

There's no mysql connection, how am I to make a request?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is not very clear. Please try to elaborate on your question and formulate it as clear and simple as possible. A short example of what you have done, might help.

Answer (score 0):

First make php code for fetch data from database. Then encode data to json_encode.

You can retrieve json data from android.

Read 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html